# create and copy individual subroutines to separate files from a file having n sub routine definitions

Tags: perl

I have a file which contains n number of sub routine definitions like following (every routine starts with `sub` and ends with a keyword `bar`):

```
sub foo()
contents
bar

sub good ()
contents
bar

sub right ()
contents
bar
```

I want to create three files called `foo.s`, `good.s` and `right.s` and write the respective subroutines into corresponding files. I tried the following script but got into improper management of global/local variables as I am completely new to Perl scripting. How can I achieve this?

```
      my $op = 0;

      my $fnamet = $ARGV[0];
      if(not defined $fnamet) {
              die "Top file name not known\n";
      }
      my $srcfile = "source/$fnamet.s";
      print "$srcfile\n";
      open (SRC, $srcfile) or die "Couldn't find source file\n";

      foreach $line (<SRC>) {
              if ($op == 0) {
                      strtwrite($line, $op);
              } elsif ($op == 1) {
                      stopwrite($line, $op);
              }
      }
      if ($op == 1) {
              print "Some sub is missing bar statement or having\n";
              print "additional sub statement";
              close (DST);
      }
      close (SRC);
  }

  sub strtwrite {
      unless ($_[0] =~ /^\s*sub\s*.*/) {
              print "Searching for a sub start\n";
              $op = 0;
      } else {
              print "A sub start found\n";
              print "$_[0]\n";
              my @temp = (split /[\s,();]+/, $_[0]);
              my $strt = '';
              if($temp[1] =~ 'sub') {
                      print "Comparing with sub pass \n";
                      $strt = $temp[2];
              } else {
                      print "Comparing with sub fail \n";
                      $strt = $temp[1];
              }
              my $fnameb = "dstcodes/$strt.s";
             print "\n\n $fnameb \n\n";
              open (DST, '>$fnameb') or die "Couldn't open sub file\n";
              print DST $_[0];
              $op = 1;
      } 
  }

  sub stopwrite {
      unless ($_[0] =~ /^\s*bar\s*.*/) {
              # Copy till the bar is found
              print "Searching for an bar\n";
              print DST $_[0];
              $op = 1;
      } else {
              # Close the current destination file and start waiting 
              # for next SUB start
              print "A matching BAR found\n";  
              print DST $_[0];
              close (DST);
              $op = 0;
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

This is relatively straightforward using a lexical variable for the output file handle (which it is best to do anyway).

This program simply opens an output file on `$dst` whenever a `sub` line is found in the input. Then the current input line is printed to `$dst` and everything just works.

A few hints:

- *Always* `use strict` and `use warnings` at the start of your program
- Declare your variables as close as possible to their first point of use, rather than all together at the top of the program
- *Always* use lexical file handles and the three-parameter form of `open`, and include the value of `$!` in the `die` string so that you know the *reason* for the failure
- If you *don't* put a newline on the end of your `die` string then Perl will display the file name and line number where the problem occurred
- Use `while` to read through a file, rather than `for`. The latter will unnecessarily read the entire file into memory before the loop starts, which will become a problem for large files

```
use strict;
use warnings;

die "Top file name not known" unless @ARGV;
my $srcfile = "source/$ARGV[0].s";

open my $src, $srcfile or die "Unable to open '$srcfile': $!";
my $dst;
while (<$src>) {
  if (/^\s*sub\s+(\w+)/) {
    my $file = "dstcodes/$1.s";
    open $dst, '>', $file or die "Unable to open '$file' for output: $!";
  }
  print $dst $_ if $dst;
}

close $dst if $dst;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try `while` loop with `/g` regex,

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my ($fnamet) = @ARGV;
open my $fh, "<", $fnamet or die $!;
my $str = do { local $/; <$fh> };
close $fh or die $!;

while ($str =~ /(sub \s+ (\w+) .+?) bar/xgs) {
  my ($cont, $name) = ($1, $2);

  open my $o, ">", "$name.s" or die $!;
  print $o $cont;
  close $o or die $!;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, first there is a quick fix to your problem: We pass a reference to the `$op` variable to the subs. Perl references are similar to C pointers. We can obtain a reference with the `\` operator. We can *dereference* a ref like `$$opref`, that is the sigil `$` doubles as dereference operator.

```
if ($op == 0) {
        strtwrite($line, \$op);
} elsif ($op == 1) {
        stopwrite($line, \$op);
}
```

and then in the subs, we unpack the arguments:

```
sub stopwrite {
  my ($line, $opref) = @_;

  ...
  $$opref = 1;
}
```

(There is the shorter solution of skipping the references and assigning to `$_[1]`, but that isn't exactly readable).

---

But you see, I'm kind of objected to this technique because all of this is *action-at-a-distance*-ish and mutable state often makes simple things rather complicated.

Let's assume we have a subroutine `extract_sub` that skips any junk lines until it finds a sub declaration, extracts the sub to a file, and returns once the sub is terminated by the `bar` marker. To do this, `extract_sub` takes a *file handle* as argument. So our main part looks like:

```
use strict; use warnings;
use autodie;  # automatic error messages for `open`

@ARGV or die "Usage: $0 input-file\n";
my $filename = shift @ARGV;

# using “lexical filehandes” and an explicit open mode “<”:
open my $source, "<", $filename;

extract_subs($source) until eof $source;

# $source is closed automatically
```

Now, what happens in `extract_subs`? First, we unpack the arguments into variables, which is easier to read:

```
sub extract_subs {
  my ($input) = @_;
```

Next, we start discarding lines until we see a `sub`:

```
  my $output;
  while (my $declaration = <$input>) {
    if ($declaration =~ /^\s* sub \s+ (\w+)/x) {
      my $name = $1;
      open $output, ">", "dstcodes/$name.s";  # no error handling because autodie
      print { $output } $declaration;  # print the whole declaration to this file
      last;  # leave the loop
    }
  }
  # check that the loop didn't abort because $input was exhausted:
  return unless defined $output;
```

We opened the file inside that loop to be able to print `$declaration` right there.

Now that we have opened the output file and are inside the sub, we print all lines to the `$output` until we see the termination line:

```
# implicitly read into $_ default variable
while (<$input>) {
  print { $output } $_;
  return if /^\s*bar\b/;  # exit the whole subroutine, not just the loop
}
# If this code is reached, then $input was exhausted before finding the "bar" terminator
die "A sub was not terminated with a bar statement"
```

---

I think this code is more elegant and easier to understand. Here are a few things you **shouldn't** do:

- Ancient forms of `open` like bareword filehandles, or specifying no open mode. *Always* use the three-argument form: `open my $filehandle, "<", $filename or die "Can't open $filename: $!"` – the `or die` part can be omitted when using `autodie`.
- Using globals, like bareword filehandles. They make code buggy and harder to understand.
- Not using `strict` and `warnings`. All those error messages seem pesky, but they generally point to *real problems* which should be fixed rather than ignored.
- Using flags to specify the state of a parser. If you factor your code into *appropriate* subroutines with good return values, such communication channels are not needed. Remember that you can return multiple values from a Perl subroutine if necessary.
- Using `=~` as a general string operator. It is used for *regex matching*. If you want to test for string *equality*, then use the `eq` operator.
- Testing for specific truth values. If you only care if a variable is true or false, then use it in a condition directly: `if ($foo) { bar() } else { baz() }`. This is more robust than requiring *specific* values, e.g. `if ($foo == 1) { bar() } elsif ($foo = 0) { baz() }`.
- Using the `unless ($cond) { A } else { B }` construction. This is often rather hard to understand. Either of `if (not $cond) { A} else { B }` or `if ($cond) { B } else { A }` is better.
- Not reading “Modern Perl”. Once you feel comfortable with programming Perl, you should read that book (it's also available online) to learn current best practices.